# How to axios.patch () data from a vuex store

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, vuex, patch

I've been at it for days but i keep getting errors and no update to the api data. This is the code in my store.. The issue is with the update user action

this is an update

the action in store

```
    async updateUsers(id){
     await axios.patch(`${resource_url}${id}`, id).then(response => {
     console.log(response.data)  
     })
    }
```

the click method that is dispatching the action

```
methods: {
    renameUsers(){
        this.$store.dispatch('updateUsers')
    }
}
```

ive been trying a mix of fixes so see what works so the code keeps changing alot.

Comment: You're misusing async/await. One of its benefits is that it helps with `then` functions scope. Don't use `then`. This applies only to console.log problem. As for patch, the question doesn't contain enough information and cannot be answered. *i keep getting errors* - what error? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: errors are patch (url) 404

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404

Comment: Currently you're the only person who's able to debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see if you passed an id in dispatch

```
this.$store.dispatch('updateUsers', /* pass id here */)
```